# Blender Build 2.6 in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: xcode, build, osx-lion, blender-2.61

I have a problem with building Blender 2.6 in Mac OS X Lion. 
What I have done is described here

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Doc/Building_Blender/Mac

but I discovered that I have to install Xcode 3, using these instructions.

http://blog.laurent.etiemble.com/index.php?post/2011/09/04/Xcode-3.2.6%2C-Lion-and-PPC-support.

However, I discovered some errors and now, while I am trying to do this:

> A.) Scons Copy blender/config/darwin-config.py into the blender folder
>   and rename the file to user-config.py:
>
> cd ~/blender-build/blender cp
>   build_files/scons/config/darwin-config.py user-config.py Then open
>   user-config.py and change the flags at the very top to match your
>   needs ( Do never(!) change darwin-config.py directly ) :
>
> MACOSX_ARCHITECTURE needs to be set to the correct architecture : ppc,
>   i386 (Intel 32bit) or x86_64 (Intel 64bit) After a first successful
>   build, you can afterwards ("expert mode") tweak the other settings to
>   make an optimized build.
>
> Note that 32bit architectures (ppc & i386) are built by default with
>   10.4SDK. If you are using OSX 10.6, you may need to install the 10.4 SDK that is an optional package in xcode install. Then launch the
>   build:
>
> python scons/scons.py -j 2 Change "2" to the actual number of CPU
>   cores you have in your system to accelerate the build process.
>
> If everything went fine, the resulting blender.app will reside here:
>   blender-build/install/darwin/blender.app

I receive the following error

> ld: in
>   /Users/usersname/blender-build/build/darwin/lib/libbf_intern_guardedalloc.a,
>   archive has no table of contents for architecture x86_64 collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

Do you have any idea what I can do to fix this problem?
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried with XCode 4? If 64 bit build proves problematic, you could try to make a 32 bit one.

Comment: It doesn't work with Xcode 4...but anyway, I didn't need if finally...